# iOS - Problems With Creating Multiple Gesture Recognizers In Code

Tags: ios, selector, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to add some views into the screen, and I want them to have the ability to be moved by user to anywhere else in the screen ( using Pan gestures ) .

I've created the views and their content through code and it's working fine, but gesture recognizers fail to call the action method. When I touch any of the view ( whenever I try to trigger one of the recognizers ) I receive this error and application crashes :

`-[UIView panThisNote:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1b0500`

This is the code that creates the views and assigns required values :

```
for (int i = 1; i <= self.NOP; i++)
{
    UIView *stateView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((arc4random()%700)-100 , (20 * 91) + 378 + ((arc4random()%600)+200), 325 , 188)];
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 325, 188)];
    imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"L7_stickyNote_%d.png",arc4random()%4]];
    int randomSign = ( arc4random()%2 == 0 ? 1 : -1 );
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( randomSign * M_PI/((arc4random()%35)+2) );
    stateView.transform = transform;
    [stateView addGestureRecognizer:[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:stateView action:@selector(panThisNote:)]];
    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 283, 146)];
    textView.text = [self.finalStates objectAtIndex:i-1];
    textView.userInteractionEnabled = NO ;
    textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    textView.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Noteworthy" size:14];
    [stateView addSubview:imgView];
    [stateView addSubview:textView];
    [self.BGPaper addSubview:stateView];
}
```

I'm not sure but I guess I know why this is happening ( I think it's because of memory allocation of objects created with same name inside a loop ) but I've no idea how should I add GestureRecognizers and fix this.

It would be great if someone can correct me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your gesture recognizer is targeting `stateView`, which is a `UIView`, and obviously therefore doesn't implement panThisNote:.  You need to rethink what you are doing.

Comment: Tnx ... I replaced "stateView" with "self" ... Everything's fine now :)